# Extract information from website using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the information on a file using nokogiri.

The information generated isn't an xml or html file.. so not sure how to get this!

```
def get_summoner_account
    url = "http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getSummonerByName?summonerName=Heggom&key=0r57xO0H2A7ukQi6gUbG "
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    name = doc.xpath("name").collect(&:text)
    acctID = doc.xpath("acctID").collect(&:text)
    summonerId = doc.xpath("summonerId").collect(&:text)

    puts accID
    puts name
    puts summonerID

end
```

Comment: This data is in JSON format. Xpath is for XML/XHTML, not for JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data at the link you provided is in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format, not XML, so Nokogiri is not appropriate.

To get the data you want, you can just use Ruby's [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to get the data and JSON to parse it:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

def get_summoner_account
  uri = URI("http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getSummonerByName?summonerName=Heggom&key=0r57xO0H2A7ukQi6gUbG")

  resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  hash = JSON(resp.body)

  name = hash['name']
  acctId = hash['acctId']
  summonerId = hash['summonerId']

  ...

end
```

Comment: Just so you know, his output is actually `acctId` not `accID`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Using your answer I get "undefined local variable or method `uri" though.

Comment: ak sorry edited my answer too many times, `url` should be `uri`. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Also, the line with the `hash` in it should be `hash = JSON(resp.body)`. The `body` part was missing. I've updated the answer.

Comment: A wee follow up, if I cannot pull the information from the json file (the API is down on the site I'm using at the moment), how would I go about putting in an exception?

Comment: You can check if all the values or nil and if they are, raise an exception. Something like `raise "API Down!" if hash['name'].nil? && hash['acctId'].nil? && hash['summonerId'].nil?`. You could probably make that shorter.

Comment: Thanks Sunny. If you don't mind, another question. if I were to look further down the tree, how would I get the value? I've tried `playerStatSummaries.playerStatSummarySet[2].maxRating`, but it doesn't seem to grab the data? The JSON data that I'm trying to grab is here http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getPlayerStats?accountId=23529170&season=CURRENT&key=0r57xO0H2A7ukQi6gUbG

Comment: Infact, I can't even go down one level, to lets say, `leaverPenaltyStats.level`.

Comment: @Martin e.g. You can just pass the key in square brackets, so e.g. `hash['playerStatSummaries']['playerStatSummarySet'][2]['maxRating']` will return `1237`. You should read up on the Ruby [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) class, that's all this is.

Comment: And: `hash['leaverPenaltyStats']['level']`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I've tried so many variations this afternoon!

Comment: You know, I actually tried `[playerStatSummaries][playerStatSummarySet][2][maxRating]`.. goddamn it! :) Thanks again!

Comment: I feel like an idiot for keep asking questions! It would seem the `[playerStatSummarySet][THIS_NUMBER]` changes regularly, so I cant rely on just `hash['playerStatSummaries']['playerStatSummarySet'][2]['rating']` I need to search for which 'set' the RankedSolo5x5 value is, then I can get the rating. Having a look around, it seems the fetch argument would be best? Fetch for the set where `RankedSolo5x5` exists then output the 'rating'?

Comment: I think you should post a separate question :)

Comment: I think that might be a good idea :) Or if you could point me in the right direction? is what I'm looking for on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-assoc?

Answer (score 1):

The output is json, not html. You can extract it using Ruby standard library.

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

page = open('http://elophant.com/api/v1/euw/getSummonerByName?summonerName=Heggom&key=0r57xO0H2A7ukQi6gUbG')

contents = page.read

h = JSON.parse(contents)

puts a['acctId']
=> 22031699
puts h['name']
=> "Heggom"
puts h['summonerId']
=> 19335440
```

Comment: Thank you Sunny! very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Writing API clients is best done with a library suited for that. `HTTParty` and `Rest-client` are good gems for this. They can detect the response type and parse it for you. In addition, they allow you to create classes that model the service, so your code stays tidy and DRY.

Here's your example rewritten using [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/).

```
class Elophant
  include HTTParty

  base_uri "http://elophant.com/api/v1/"
  format :json
  @key = "0r57xO0H2A7ukQi6gUbG"

  def self.get_summoner(name)
    get('/euw/getSummonerByName', :query => {'summonerName' => name, 'key' => @key})
  end
end
```

Then the usage is very simple:

```
summoner = Elophant.get_summoner("Heggom")

puts summoner['acctId'] #=> 22031699

puts summoner['name'] #=> "Heggom"

puts summoner['summonerId'] #=> 19335440
```

Note: normally HTTParty determines the type automatically from the headers, but this site is sending a header saying the content is `text/html` when it should be `application/json`. Therefore we need to add the line `format :json`.

The nice thing is that the details are nicely tucked away in a class that you own. You can expand on it: let's say you wanted to make it usable by others with a different key, you can just create an initializer which will allow you to pass in the key `elophant = Elophant.new(key)`, etc. Even if you don't need to do this type of thing, I find this solution to be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'll definitely look into this. Much appreciated.